# How to pass data between controller, checker and back using callback closures Swift

Tags: ios, swift, callback, closures

I'm a newbie in Swift and this is my very first question I want to ask the community.
I have a viewcontroller with a textField, custom button and a label and also I have a separate checker to check whether the entered in textField word is correct or not. So when I push the button the checker is checking and changing the color of the label (green/ red / transparent if textfield.text is empty. How can I implement this using callback closure?  Thank you so much in advance!

Here is my ViewController:

```
final class FeedViewController: UIViewController {

    private let checkTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = MyCustomTextField(
            font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16),
            textColor: .black,
            backgroundColor: .white,
            placeholder: "Enter the word")
        
        return textField
    }()
    
    private lazy var checkButton: UIButton = {
        let button = MyCustomButton(
            title: "Check the word",
            titleColor: .white,
            backgroundColor: .systemGray,
            backgroundImage: nil) {

        }
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        return button
    }()
    
    private let colorLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.alpha = 0
        label.toAutoLayout()
        return label
    }()
 
    private let checker: CheckTextField
    
    init(checker: CheckTextField) {
        self.checker = checker
        super .init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
```

Here is my Checker:

```
class CheckTextField {
    
    private let correctWord = "correct word"
    
    func check( word: String) {
        

    }
}
```

I have managed to complete this task with notifications, but closures for me are too much complicated :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closure is actually a parameter of the method that receives and calls it, so if you want `check(word:)` to call some closure when it finishes checking, you'll need to add that as a parameter:

```
func check(word: String, closure: ()->Void)
```

If you want to pass a parameter to the closure, you'll need to specify that too:

```
func check(word: String, closure: (status: CheckResult)->Void)
```

I just made up `CheckResult` here; I just needed some type that you can use to convey the result of the check. It could be a an enumeration, for example:

```
enum CheckResult {
    case ok;
    case bad;
    case empty;
}
```

Now, inside your `check` function, you can call the closure with the appropriate value, like: `closure(.ok)`. To be more concrete, let's fill in your empty function:

```
class CheckTextField {
    private let correctWord = "apple"
    
    func check(word: String, closure: (_ status: CheckResult)->Void) {
        if word.count == 0 {
            closure(.empty)
        } else if word == correctWord {
            closure(.ok)
        } else {
            closure(.bad)
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can use it this way:

```
let checker = CheckTextField()

checker.check(word:"apple") { print($0) }       // ok
checker.check(word:"pear") { print($0) }        // bad
checker.check(word:"jackfruit") { print($0) }   // bad
checker.check(word:"") { print($0) }            // empty
```

You can replace the `print($0)` with code to set the label color or whatever else you might want to do. That's nice, because it keeps details about your view out of the `CheckTextField` class.

Comment: I would add to the answer above, that you can also use `Regex` for a more complex checks than just word comparison.

See the link below for examples:
https://nshipster.com/swift-regular-expressions/

Comment: thanks for your support! I finally managed to solve my problem with your help :)

Answer (score 3):

you can define  your clousure in data sending class as follow

```
class DataSenderClass  {
var dataPassClousure:((String)->Void)?
func sendHere(){
    // i am invoking closure from here
    dataPassClousure?("hi i am data")
}
```

}
here is **dataPassClousure** accepting  string as argument(you can adjust according to your choice or can use object as well or  can also pass multiple arguments to your closure) to be sent/passed to receiver class.
Just listen to fresh data in your data receiver class as follow

```
class DataReceiverClass {
let senderObject = DataSenderClass()
func receiveHere() {
    //each time data change from sendHere function this closure invoke . perform your action
    senderObject.dataPassClousure = {arug1 in
        print("received data is \(arug1)")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you!  Surprisingly it is very simple and effective )))